# jQuery Unexpected token ILLEGAL - line 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I know this has been asked before, but I'm yet to see anyone with the problem on line 1.

All of my JS files are getting this console error (in every browser). I'm loading jQuery from Google libraries which is working fine and not getting an error, however a jQuery plugin (fancybox) is getting the error and this code hasn't been touched.

I have no idea why the rest of my files are getting this error as they were working all day yesterday and this morning.

I saw in a few cases the error was caused by unreadable characters, but I don't think I have any on this page.

The page can be found at http://b9media.co.uk/tbw.

My own JS file starts as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // log-in functionality
    var signin = $('#signin');
    var login = $('#login');

    signin.click(function() {
        login.show(function() {
            login.css("margin-left", 0);
        });
        signin.animate({opacity: 0}, 300, function() {
            signin.addClass('hide');
        });
    });



    // move sign-up box on mobile

    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 781) {
        $('#signup-grab').appendTo("#append");
    };
});
```

Comment: your file encoding seems to be messed up somehow...

Comment: Ah! Apparently it's in Western ISO (Latin 1), should it be something different?

Comment: @lucas572, I always used `UTF-8` and didn't encountered any problem about it.

Comment: Try UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM.

Comment: UTF-16 seems to get me the closest so far (see current page). I'll try the UTF-8 without BOM :) But can you tell me what BOM is? In my encoding options I only have UTF-8

Comment: you are getting this error only when you import that plugin? which one are you importing first, jquery or it's plugin?

Comment: You've got some mighty weird characters in all your loaded files: js, css, you name it. I don't see anything in the initial request's http headers, but it *looks* like there are some strange characters right before the `<!DOCTYPE`. If I download it with wget or curl, it believes it is a binary file.

Comment: I get this error on everything. If I host jQuery myself, I get the error on that, if I import any js file, the error is on that too. Converting everything to UTF-16 has helped I think, all of my JS is loading. Are the characters still messed up though?